# How to store files in MySQL database using MySQL Workbench?

Tags: html, mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to store .html files in a MySQL database (using MySQL Workbench). At the moment I'm trying to do `load_file('filepath')` so the contents of the .html file can be read and converted to string and that string will be stored in the table in the DB. But the problem is that it seems to always return null so I can't check if it's actually working.

I know there are 4 criteria to pass for load_file to work but I don't know which scripts I have to execute to grant the privileges. Since I'm trying to convert the contents of the file to string, maybe there is another way more efficient to store the whole .html file into the DB and if yes could anyone show me how to do this? My MySQL server has a username of root and working on Mac OS.

Comment: ` I don't know which scripts I have to execute to grant the privileges` - you don't have to, use the functionality built into MySQL workbench to grant users access. If the function returns null, then it did not work.  Btw, it is not always a good idea to store files in a database.

Comment: @Shadow So do you think It's better to leave the file in a folder in the computer and let the contents get copied into string in the DB table? Because I have a Java web server I created myself and I'd like it to connect to the MySQL DB and fetch the data/files from there instead of the web server searching through the computer's directory. I'm not sure if the way I want is the most efficient or not.

Comment: You seem to mix different aspects here. What is this `load_file` function about? It hasn't to do with MySQL Workbench nor MySQL. What is your actual problem? Be more specific and show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @MikeLischke This is what I've tried so far: `SELECT load_file('file:///Users/Josh/iCloud Drive/Desktop/MyServer/src/html/index.html');
` and yes it has something to do with MySQL https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html.

Comment: Didn't know this is a MySQL function. You shouldn't rely on everybody knowing this function off their heads. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [load_file function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) says that:

> To use this function, the file must be located on the server host, you must specify the full path name to the file, and you must have the FILE privilege. The file must be readable by all and its size less than max_allowed_packet bytes. If the secure_file_priv system variable is set to a nonempty directory name, the file to be loaded must be located in that directory.

So there are a number of conditions to check if you actually **can** load the file. Start by checking if your user has the FILE privilege and that the file is accessible by your MySQL server.

Answer (score 0):

For people who's looking for, this is how I did it. 
I have a table as

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `UPLOAD_FILE` mediumblob
);
```

and I save a file smiley.jpg as

```
INSERT INTO test (`ID`, `UPLOAD_FILE`) VALUES ('1', LOAD_FILE('E:/smiley.jpg'));
```